# Regarding the subprocess module and the keyword argument shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am a beginner in Python and can you kindly help me understand the following concept.

If I do the following,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['ls'])
```

Here we know that the key word argument, **shell** is set to **False** by default so that the 'ls' does not run on the shell. But my question is **if it does not run on the shell, on where does it run and how can it give me an output?**

Answer (score -1):

I have a windows system but it should work the same.

For getting the output of subprocess you can use check_output.

On windows -

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["dir"], shell=True)
```

running this code without shell=True will result in an error.

If I want to run the code above with shell=False
I would do something like this -

```
subprocess.check_output(["cmd","/c","dir"], shell=False)
```

Notice -

> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh.

That means when you pass command and use shell=True
it will use /bin/sh to run that command.